# Redirect page after 3 views from same IP address

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a javascript or html code that can redirect to another web page if the user comes 3 times on the same webpage? I see this sometimes on websites that have a trial version.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Use a cookie or localStorage to implement a view counter.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Do you have a similar code that I can use?

Comment: Please show some effort of your own. Try to implement it yourself, and if you can't get it to work show what you've written and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Pretty open ended for SO. Besides, redirecting based on IP or cookies is not a good way to introduce a paywall to a site. Easy to get around. I suggest researching paywall methods on the web.

Answer (score 1):

As **jods** said, doing it client-sided (JavaScript) is insecure. A simple 'clean' of your browser history undo's the trick..

But here's a quick example how you can do it with localStorage:

```
/*
    use this to reset the code:
    localStorage.setItem('visited', 0);
*/

var views = localStorage.getItem('visited');

views = (views===undefined)? 1 : parseInt(views)+1;

if (views<=3)
{
    localStorage.setItem('visited', views);
    document.write('You visited this page for the: ' + views + ' time!');
}
else
{
    document.write('You can only view it 3 times!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better handled server-side. I don't know what technology you use (PHP, .NET, Java), but the server can easily check the IP address of the client and return a different answer after 3 times, like a redirect response.

Handling it client-side is possible as suggested with cookies or localStorage, but that's very ineffective if your goal is security (e.g. a trial restriction). Cookies and localStorage are trivial to clear and the user grants himself 3 new free accesses.

Comment: We use PHP, I will try to find something on the web, thanks for pointing to the right direction. I thought maybe there was a easy way to do this like a simple javascript, but it seems harder than it looks :)

Comment: It's easy to do in javascript as well, it's just not secure. It all depends on what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** do this *solely*  with Javascript, you would have to communicate with the server and implement it that way.

If you would like to replace **IP Address** with **Device** then you could use `localStorage` or a cookie.

Here's an example using `localStorage`

```
var count = Number( localStorage.visitCount );

if(isNaN(count)) {
   localStorage.visitCount = 1
} else {
   localStorage.visitCount++
}

if( +localStorage.visitCount === 3 ) {
   window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com')
}
```

Comment: Sow I have to wrap this into a javascript code? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Jan You would put it in your html code inside `<script>code...</script>` or use an external file

Comment: thank you for your answer but it's not working unfortunately. I test it in the head and body.